# Printing a page: Content only on 2nd Page?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, printing

I need to **print** web content (HTML/CSS). One of the things I need to do is to print some stuff (page Number, title of the doc) **on every page but the first**.

Is there a way to make a div (or other element) to appear only on Pages >=2?

I do NOT have any manual page-breaks

jQuery may be used

Answer (score -2, accepted):

The CSS `@page` directive with `:first` to apply CSS to the first page of an html print

I give an example with `#header` and `#footer` that might hep you

```
@media print {
    @page  {
        /* Styles for every page other than first page */
        #header {
            position: fixed;
            display: block;
            top: 0;
        }
        #footer {
            position: fixed;
            display: block;
            bottom: 0;
        }
    }
    @page :first {
        /* override the styles for the first page */
        #header {
            display: none;
        }
        #footer {
            display: none;
        }
    }
}
```